# Dictionary assignment to tuple-keys in other dictionary with map() function

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, variable-assignment, map-function

Suppose we have a dict d1 and a dict d2. Now, imagine that d2 is a value of tuple-keys inside d1, just as follows:

```
d1 = {}
d2 = {}

for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        d1[(j,i)] = d2

print d1
```

Output:

```
{(0, 1): {}, (1, 2): {}, (3, 2): {}, (0, 0): {}, (3, 3): {}, (3, 0): {}, (3, 1): {}, (2, 1): {}, (0, 2): {}, (2, 0): {}, (1, 3): {}, (2, 3): {}, (2, 2): {}, (1, 0): {}, (0, 3): {}, (1, 1): {}}
```

Now comes the question:

How can I do it without using for loops, considering that I can't assign anything inside lambda expressions? How can I do something like this:

```
map((lambda x: x =¹ "t"),[(j,i) for j in range(16) for i in range(16)]) # ¹: Inadmissible syntax.
```

Comment: Do you want `d2` to be shared among all the keys, or do you want a *separate, new* dictionary per value?

Comment: Actually, a separate one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays):

```
d1 = {(i, j): {} for i in range(4) for j in range(4)}
```

In addition, you can use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to produce the indices in a single loop:

```
from itertools import product

d1 = {(i, j): {} for i, j in product(range(4), repeat=2)}
```

Both these expressions create *separate* nested dictionaries; the `key: value` expressions are evaluated each loop iteration.

Demo:

```
>>> {(i, j): {} for i in range(4) for j in range(4)}
{(0, 1): {}, (1, 2): {}, (3, 2): {}, (0, 0): {}, (3, 3): {}, (3, 0): {}, (3, 1): {}, (2, 1): {}, (0, 2): {}, (2, 0): {}, (1, 3): {}, (2, 3): {}, (2, 2): {}, (1, 0): {}, (0, 3): {}, (1, 1): {}}
>>> from itertools import product
>>> {(i, j): {} for i, j in product(range(4), repeat=2)}
{(0, 1): {}, (1, 2): {}, (3, 2): {}, (0, 0): {}, (3, 3): {}, (3, 0): {}, (3, 1): {}, (2, 1): {}, (0, 2): {}, (2, 0): {}, (1, 3): {}, (2, 3): {}, (2, 2): {}, (1, 0): {}, (0, 3): {}, (1, 1): {}}
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you very much! I did not even KNOW about the existence of such a thing as "dictionary comprehension". I thought it was just for lists.

Comment: @EricsonWillians: there is a set comprehension as well (just drop the `: value` part, `{expression for target_list in iterable}`).